# error with math mode

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
Given a curve $\mathcal{L}$, define two functions of distance transform $\kappa_{+}$ and $\kappa_{-}$ on \mathbb{R}^{2} as
$\kappa_{+}(x) = d(x,\mathbb{R}^{2}\D), x \in \mathbb{R}^{2},                     (1)$
$\kappa_{-}(x) = d(x,\mathbb{R}^{2}\D), x \in \mathbb{R}^{2},                     (2)$
```

I get following error:

```
Undefined sequence
```

Comment: Hi Svaidya, [http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx](Welcome to tex-sx!) It's usually best to provide your code in the form of a [http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that](MWE) as it really helps those who might be able to provide assistance. Welcome!

Comment: Just to follow my previous comment- there's a danger that your question might get closed if it is not posed clearly; your question is very reasonable, but would benefit greatly from being turned into a Minimal Working Example

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful to use `mathmode` correctly; in particular, `\mathbb` needs to be in `mathmode`.

You didn't specify what the macro `\D` does, but it looks as if would you like to use the `align` environment, as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\D}{D}

\begin{document}
 Given a curve $\mathcal{L}$, define two functions of distance transform $\kappa_{+}$ 
 and $\kappa_{-}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as 
 \begin{align}
 \kappa_{+}(x) & = d(x,\mathbb{R}^{2}\D), x \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \\
 \kappa_{-}(x) & = d(x,\mathbb{R}^{2}\D), x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\D` might depend on a certain package, the `\mathbb{R}` without `$` surrounded should not produce the mentioned error, but an `missing $`. Hence `\D` should be the cause for the error (though depending on the OPs packages in use).

Comment: @Ronny thanks for your input. Have you tried compiling `\mathbb` without `$`? :)

Comment: well i was right stating, that the OPs error does not come from the math mode missing around `\mathbb R`, though the real error message then is of course `Error: \mathbb allowed only in math mode.` :)

Answer (score 1):

Please always post *complete* documents so that your problem may be reproduced. However `\mathcal` is a standard LaTeX command but `\mathbb` requires a package (such as `amssymb`)